# re-arranging entries in 2d array based on certain columns

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have an `M x N` numpy array where each row represents a data entry, the first `N-1` columns represent different parameters (independent variable), and the last column represent the data I'm interested in (dependent variable).

What's the most elegant way to re-arrange different rows such that they are sorted by the parameters?

Example:

```
# original
1                        0.1                      20                       0.30000000000000004      0.07819319717404902     
1                        1                        10                       0.2                      0.07550707294415204      
2                        0.1                      0                        0                        0.07078663749666488      
2                        0.1                      0                        0.1                      0.07284943819285646      
1                        1                        15                       0.4                      0.08047398714777267      
1                        1                        15                       0.5                      0.0820402298018169      
1                        1                        15                       0.30000000000000004      0.07819319717406738     
1                        1                        20                       0                        0.07079655446543297      
1                        1                        20                       0.1                      0.07286704639139795      
1                        1                        5                        0.4                       0.086521872154



# desired:
1                        0.1                      20                       0.30000000000000004      0.07819319717404902     
1                        1                        5                        0.4                       0.086521872154
1                        1                        10                       0.2                      0.07550707294415204      
1                        1                        15                       0.30000000000000004      0.07819319717406738
1                        1                        15                       0.4                      0.08047398714777267      
1                        1                        15                       0.5                      0.0820402298018169      
1                        1                        20                       0                        0.07079655446543297      
1                        1                        20                       0.1                      0.07286704639139795      
2                        0.1                      0                        0                        0.07078663749666488      
2                        0.1                      0                        0.1                      0.07284943819285646
```

I want the data to be sorted from the smallest in each parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you want sort ndarray on single columns using [np.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort)

Given the following matrix:

```
m = np.array([[5., 0.1, 3.4],
           [7., 0.3, 6.8],
           [3., 0.2, 5.6]])
```

This code sorts the matrix m based on column 0:

```
m[m[:,0].argsort(kind='mergesort')]
```

Result:

```
array([[3. , 0.2, 5.6],
       [5. , 0.1, 3.4],
       [7. , 0.3, 6.8]])
```

#### If you want sort ndarray on multiple columns using [np.lexsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy.lexsort)

Given:

```
a = np.array([[1,20,200], [1,30,100], [1,10,300]])
array([[  1,  20, 200],
       [  1,  30, 100],
       [  1,  10, 300]])
```

Order by column 1 and column 0:

```
a[np.lexsort((a[:,0],a[:,1]))]
# output:
array([[  1,  10, 300],
       [  1,  20, 200],
       [  1,  30, 100]])
```

**NOTE**:  The **last right-column** (or row if keys is a 2D array) is the primary sort key.

Order by all columns (starting from the right):

```
a[np.lexsort((a[:,0], a[:,1],a[:,2]))]
# output:
array([[  1,  30, 100],
       [  1,  20, 200],
       [  1,  10, 300]])
```

Or equivalently, order by all column without specifying the columns manually (following the order of the columns in the matrix starting from the right):

```
a[np.lexsort(list(map(tuple,np.column_stack(a))))]
# output:
array([[  1,  30, 100],
       [  1,  20, 200],
       [  1,  10, 300]])
```

#### Other option: Pandas is a good idea for your specific problem?

Another option is to switch to pandas. It's works, but it is some order of magnitude slower. Here are some tests on execution times:

Benchmarck data:

```
a = np.array([[1,20,200]*1000, [1,30,100]*1000, [1,10,300]*1000])
```

**Pandas version:**

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(a).sort_values(list(range(a.shape[1]))).values
# 3.66 s ± 110 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Numpy version:**

```
%%timeit
a[np.lexsort((a[:,0], a[:,1],a[:,2]))]
# 39.6 µs ± 12.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As you can see you go from the micro seconds of numpy to the seconds of the version based on pandas (about 1 million times slower). 
The choice is yours :)

Comment: Yes, but within each parameter (e.g. `3`), there are multiple other parameters. And I want to sort them in order as well. For example

    `array([[3, 0.2, 5.6],[3, 0.3, 3.4],[3, 0.4, 3.5],[5,0.1,3.4],[5,0.3,5.3],[5,0.6,9.5],[7,0.3,6.8]])`

Comment: Now I understand what you mean, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: for `a[np.lexsort(list(map(tuple,np.column_stack(a))))]`, it sorts the order in the opposite order of what I want (I want leftmost column to be the 'outer' one). So I need `a[np.lexsort((a[:,2],a[:,1],a[:,0]))` instead. How to rewrite this for arbitary number of columns?

Comment: This `a[np.lexsort(( a[:,0],a[:,1],a[:,2]))]` is equal to `a[np.lexsort(list(map(tuple, np.column_stack(a))))]` and this `a[np.lexsort(( a[:,2],a[:,1],a[:,0]))]` is equal to `a[np.lexsort(list(map(tuple, reversed(np.column_stack(a)))))]`. I updated the answer because it may not be clear that the last right-column is the primary sort key. Have I answered your question and clarified your doubt? @Physicist

Comment: Yeah now it's perfect.

Comment: Glad to have helped you once again :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lexsort`:

```
original[np.lexsort(np.rot90(original))]
```

Answer (score 1):

One option that uses `pandas`'s `sort_values`:

```
pd.DataFrame(a).sort_values(list(range(a.shape[1]))).values
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.1       , 20.        ,  0.3       ,  0.0781932 ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  5.        ,  0.4       ,  0.08652187],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        , 10.        ,  0.2       ,  0.07550707],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        , 15.        ,  0.3       ,  0.0781932 ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        , 15.        ,  0.4       ,  0.08047399],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        , 15.        ,  0.5       ,  0.08204023],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        , 20.        ,  0.        ,  0.07079655],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        , 20.        ,  0.1       ,  0.07286705],
       [ 2.        ,  0.1       ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.07078664],
       [ 2.        ,  0.1       ,  0.        ,  0.1       ,  0.07284944]])
```